# NGINX configuration file for google-bot - rewrite

Tags: nginx

I have ajax site and static version of it in folder:

```
/_escaped_fragment_/
```

My config, doesn't working:

```
# nginx configuration
location / {
    if ($query_string ~ "^_escaped_fragment_=$"){
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /_escaped_fragment_$1/index.html? break;
    }
    if ($query_string ~ "^_escaped_fragment_=(.*)$"){
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /_escaped_fragment_$1/%1/index.html? break;
    }
}
```

Google bot request:

```
"GET /?_escaped_fragment_=/page/nerjav HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
```

I just need to turn:

```
/#!/page/nerjav -> /_escaped_fragment_/page/nerjav/index.html
```

Error log:

```
2014/04/24 16:43:14 [error] 6087#0: *1 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while processing "/_escaped_fragment__escaped_fragment__escaped_fragment__escaped_fragment__escaped_fragment__escaped_fragment__escaped_fragment__escaped_fragment__escaped_fragment__escaped_fragment__escaped_fragment_//page/nerjav/index.html//page/nerjav/index.html//page/nerjav/index.html//page/nerjav/index.html//page/nerjav/index.html//page/nerjav/index.html//page/nerjav/index.html//page/nerjav/index.html//page/nerjav/index.html//page/nerjav/index.html//page/nerjav/index.html", client: 66.249.66.194, server: m-chel.ru, request: "GET /?_escaped_fragment_=/page/nerjav HTTP/1.1", host: "site.com"
2014/04/24 16:43:56 [error] 6087#0: *2 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while processing "/_escaped_fragment__escaped_fragment__escaped_fragment__escaped_fragment__escaped_fragment__escaped_fragment__escaped_fragment__escaped_fragment__escaped_fragment__escaped_fragment__escaped_fragment_//page/nerjav/index.html//page/nerjav/index.html//page/nerjav/index.html//page/nerjav/index.html//page/nerjav/index.html//page/nerjav/index.html//page/nerjav/index.html//page/nerjav/index.html//page/nerjav/index.html//page/nerjav/index.html//page/nerjav/index.html", client: 109.191.139.106, server: m-chel.ru, request: "GET /?_escaped_fragment_=/page/nerjav HTTP/1.1", host: "site.com"
```

Comment: Try to look at error.log

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how your thing works, but it looks like you're missing an `=`.

```
# nginx configuration
location / {
    if ($query_string ~ "^_escaped_fragment_=$"){
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /_escaped_fragment_=$1/index.html? break;
    }
    if ($query_string ~ "^_escaped_fragment_=(.*)$"){
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /_escaped_fragment_=$1/%1/index.html? break;
    }
}
```